# Python: make an empty issue of dictionary with keys from existing ordered dict

Tags: python, cs50

PSet 6 DNA from CS50.

I have CSV file with header and values:

```
name,AGATC,TTTTTTCT,AATG,TCTAG,GATA,TATC,GAAA,TCTG
Albus,15,49,38,5,14,44,14,12
```

And I have txt file with DNA sequence:

```
AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG
```

I can make an ordered dictionary from this data:

```
OrderedDict([('name', 'Alice'), ('AGATC', '2'), ('AATG', '8'), ('TATC', '3')])
```

For text sequence I want to make an empty dictionary with the keys of the one made from CSV file.

```
    newdict = dict.fromkeys(reader.keys(),[]) - doesn`t work - the dictionary is ordered.
```

Is it possible to make a new dictionary from the ordered (and how to do it if possible?) or "ordinary" dictionary would be better?

Comment: What does "doesn`t work - the dictionary is ordered" mean?  Keep in mind that in sufficiently recent Python versions, *unordered dictionaries no longer exist*.  Even in versions where they existed, each dict has *some* order to its keys, and that order could be exactly the same as an ordered dict just by coincidence - why would this be a problem?

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'collections.OrderedDict'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Python 3.7. Is the below what you are looking for?:

```
dna_file
name,AGATC,TTTTTTCT,AATG,TCTAG,GATA,TATC,GAAA,TCTG
Albus,15,49,38,5,14,44,14,12

with open('/home/aklaver/dna.csv', newline=None) as dna_file:  
    header_line = dna_file.readline().rstrip().split(",")
header_line                                                                                                                                                               
['name', 'AGATC', 'TTTTTTCT', 'AATG', 'TCTAG', 'GATA', 'TATC', 'GAAA', 'TCTG']

dna_dict = dict.fromkeys(header_line, [])
dna_dict                                                                                                                                                                  
{'name': [],
 'AGATC': [],
 'TTTTTTCT': [],
 'AATG': [],
 'TCTAG': [],
 'GATA': [],
 'TATC': [],
 'GAAA': [],
 'TCTG': []}
```